# How to save a record in mongo db sub document using cakephp

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I have this structure in MongoDb:

```
{
    id: 1,
    students:[
         {
             id:1,
             is_allowed: true
         },
         {
             id:2,
             is_allowed: true
         },
    ]
}
```

My problem is that I dont know how to add a new record to add another student using cakephp.

Comment: What did you try already? What tools did you use? Improve your question or you won't get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the MongoDB current version, you cant add/delete a record from the `students`. 
But you can update the whole `students` by using [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/).
But if you have integrated the [ichikaway](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/) plugin then you can use the `$this->save()` where you have to set the `collection id` for updating purpose which will work exactly how the 'cakephp` functionality works with mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [this](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) plugin to used mongoDB datasource. The Author, [ichikaway](https://github.com/ichikaway) has explained nicely [here](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/wiki/How-to-deal-with-SubDocument) how to deal with subdocument in cakephp.

I have not tested it,but you can try something like this in your view to add:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model.students.is_allowed');
```

your controller, Model(if you have not specified schema) will remain same.